# How to make a chart in canvas with bars with the bars having the height of the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, html5-canvas, height

I have to make a bar in canvas with vanilla JS, no charts.js or jquery. The bars are too long for the canvas size, so it doesn't show the full length of the bars. How can I scale the bars so that they fit the hard coded canvas height?

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>chart</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>


<style> canvas { 
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
</style>

<script>

window.onload = function canvas() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let data = [['A', 439], ['B', 228.23], ['C', 2580.39], ['D', 279]];
  let barwidth = 50;
  let ygap = 30; 
  let bargap = 100; 
  let x = 50;

  y = canvas.height - ygap;

  canvas.width = data.length * (bargap) + x;

  ctx.moveTo(x - 5, y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y); // Base line of graph 
  ctx.stroke();

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ctx.textAlign = 'left';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText(data[i][0], x, y + 5); // Write base text for classes 

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    y1 = y - data[i][1]; // Coordinate for top of the Bar 
    x1 = x;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText(data[i][1], x1, y1 - 20); // text at top of the bar 

    ctx.fillStyle = 'black'; // fill Colur of bar  
    ctx.fillRect(x1, y1, barwidth, data[i][1]);// Filled bar

    x += bargap
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the `height` of the `canvas`:

document.getElementById('canvas').height

so, this will be the coordinate of the downmost points. The top of the canvas will have a coordinate of 0. This `function` calculates the coordinate of a given percent:

```
function percent(input, canvasHeight) {
    return canvasHeight - (canvasHeight * input / 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, on which lines do I have to use this function for it to scale?

Comment: @TimmyJohnson percent(75, canvas.height) is to be calculated to find out the top-left point of your bar (in this case 75% was assumed) and the height of the bar will be canvas.height - (canvas.height * 75 / 100).